Jquery sortable grid with different height boxes
I want to make a jquery sortable dashboard for my users. The dashboard has blocks with different sizes. However if I move small blocks on the right of a big block, they sort correct, but the other side of the block they don't.
preview dashboard

How can I fill the empty space with for example item 6?
Here's my jsfiddle: Jsfiddle


$(".grid")
  .sortable({
    connectWith: "li",
    tolerance: "intersect",
    opacity: 0.8,
    dropOnEmpty: true,
    revert: true,
    placeholder: "placeholder",
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    refreshPositions: true,
    forceHelperSize: true,
  })
  .disableSelection()
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.grid {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 555px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid li {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: #F6F6F6;
  font-family: "Tahoma";
  color: #1C94C4;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 22px;
  line-height: 80px;
  float: left;
  width: 254px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <h2>Sortable Grid</h2>

  <ul class="grid">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li style="height: 200px; display: list-item;">Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li style="height: 200px; display: list-item;">Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
  </ul>
</section>




I made you a snippet HERE using the [<>] snippet editor

You may use css column https://jsfiddle.net/8wyb7hor/1 or css masonry(firefox) https://jsfiddle.net/8wyb7hor/

I can't use colums because there will be many more boxes.

Can someone help me out?
